# jsp - страница не видит css

Tags: css, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Такая проблема, если в настройках IDE по дефолту при запуске приложения указать такой URL - адрес: **http://localhost:8080/views/todolist.jsp**, то стиль применяется, но если так **http://localhost:8080/views/todolist**, то jsp страница отображается без стиля. Вот код сервлета:

```
@WebServlet(name = "todolist", urlPatterns = "/todolist")
public class TodoList extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher(TODOLIST_PAGE).forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: как подключен стиль, где лежит?

Comment: @naiad09, стиль подключен так: <link rel="stylesheet" href="../views/css/main.css">. В папке views лежит jsp файл и в этой же папке (views) лежит папка css со стилями